# Query Row count from Grouped EF query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

I have this query to group the levels of a particular row in EF

```
var awards = from a in context.Awards
             where a.TWID == employee.TWID
             group a by a.AwardLevel;
```

This gives me the awards for each level (1-4) what I'm trying to figure out is how to extract the count from the awards for a specific level.

```
ie: level1.count,level2.count etc.
```

I know this should be some simple lambda expression or something but I just can't get it.

**UPDATE** What I'm looking for is a way **NOT** to write 4 different queries. For example:

```
var level1 = awards.Level[0]
var level2 = awards.Level[1]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
var awards = from a in context.Awards
             where a.TWID == employee.TWID
             group a by a.AwardLevel into award
             select new
            {
               AwardLevel = award.Key,
               Count = award.Count()
            };
```

Update based on updated question:

```
var awards = (from a in context.Awards
                 where a.TWID == employee.TWID
                 group a by a.AwardLevel into award
                 select new
                {
                   AwardLevel = award.Key,
                   Count = award.Count()
                }).ToDictionary( t => t.AwardLevel, t => t.Count );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but What I'm looking for is a way NOT to write 4 different queries. For example: var level1 = awards.Level[1]...

Comment: @JohnSwaringen what do you mean? Do you mean you want to pivot your results? Strictly speaking, its not entirely possible (what you are asking for) as C# is a strict typed language, and every variable needs to be declared. If you are worried about number of database calls, don't...this should only make a single DB call.

Comment: @John Swaringen: See my updated answer to see if it answers your question (I'm not sure I understand what you mean)

Comment: I'm trying to get a count of the group rows and put them into a variable.  For example:

var level1 = awards[1]

I need it to have a for each level (5 levels) or figure out a test for null.

Comment: @Khan, That's almost there.  What I need to be able to do is to assign the var to a variable based on if it exists or not.  For example

var level1 = awards[1]
var level2 = awards[2]

I need to have one for each level 1-5 but awards is only returning two keys.  How do I check to see if a key is null?

Comment: @Khan, I got it.  I just had to use var level1 = awards.ContainsKey(1) ? awards[1] : 0  etc.  Thanks for the help.